# Xpages attach event to partial refresh of pager in Data View

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

In a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443882/xpages-bootstrap-and-data-views) I asked how to add a bootstrap class to a Data View. The answer was to add the class to the "table.dataview" in a script block. After the table is created the class is applied and all is well.

But when I use a pager the formatting disappears. I am using a partial refresh on the pager to only refresh the data table but doing so means that the bootstrap class does not get applied to the table.

I believe I need to add an event handler that will attach to the refresh action of the dataView to add the class. However I cannot get the event handler to work.

My code for the event handler is below.

```
<xp:eventHandler refreshMode="partial" submit="true"
            id="applyCSS" refreshId="dataView1" event="parialRefresh"
            value="what" loaded="false">
            <xp:this.binding><![CDATA[#{javascript:"pager1"}]]></xp:this.binding>
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:("table.dataview").addClass("table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-condensed")}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
```

Oliver, the rendered=false was simply a typo - I was testing something and needed to temporarily suppress that.

Oliver and Paul,

Last night I was able to get the partial refresh to work.

I ran across [this post by Mark Roden](http://xomino.com/2014/10/29/binding-jquery-code-to-an-xpages-partialrefresh-using-dom-mutation-events/) which explained how to do it. There were two different ways to accomplish this, one less and one more efficient. The code I used is below.

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock3">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[$('.dataView1PanelWrapper').on("DOMNodeInserted", function(){
    $("table.dataview").addClass("table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-condensed")
})]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:scriptBlock>
```

However, and isn't there almost always a however in Xpages, I have some sortable columns in the view and clicking on the sort brings up the same problem! I lose the class assignment!

So now I would have to intercept that event too, right?

Concerned where this will end. Don't like the idea of DOM Manipulation, and only want to do it if I have too.

I started by using a simple view. It worked great, but for some reason the spacing was messed up in the pagers. I found that by moving the pagers out of the view itself, I was able to get the alignment issue fixed. I think it would be better just to use a view, as I can assign the class directly and won't have to do all this manipulation. It is however very good to know how to do this for the future.

Is that what you would suggest?

==================================================
I have tried Paul Withers suggestion using an output script. This works on the initial page load, but not on any other changes to the data view - when the pager fires, or sorting or any of that. I am close, but no cigar yet. Any suggestions?

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock5" loaded="false">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[dojo.require("dojo.behavior");

Behavior = {
    ".dataview": {
        found: function(node) {

            dojo.addClass(node,".table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-condensed");
            //node.addClass("table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-condensed");
        }
    }
}

dojo.ready(function() {
    dojo.behavior.add(Behavior);
    dojo.behavior.apply();
});

//Make sure that future pagers are also straightened out
dojo.subscribe("partialrefresh-complete", null, function(method, form, refreshId) {
    dojo.behavior.apply();
});]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your existing xp:scriptBlock with the working code inside a facet of the xe:dataView. Then the styling will get applied on initial load and on all partial refreshes.

Comment: Wow, this worked perfectly.  I jadded an output script with this code   [$("table.dataview").addClass("table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-condensed”)] to a facet in the data view and all was well. At first I added to a pager at the top of the page, but that meant it didn’t execute on the first load. I added it to a pager facet at the bottom and it works just fine. Thanks Per, and Paul and Oliver. I learned a lot doing this!

Answer (score 0):

You should call your CSJS stuff to add the class in the onComplete property of the event handler - hard to find, just highlight the event handler object in source code or outline and then open "All properties" to find the "onComplete" property. This event allows CSJS to be called.

BTW: why is the loaded property = false? The event will never we rendered.

Answer (score 0):

`dojo.behavior`, `dojo.ready` and `dojo.subscribe` should allow you to manage this. `dojo.behavior` allows you to define a particular behaviour for a particular collection of elements which will be retrieved via a Dojo query. `dojo.ready` will (I believe) run the code when the page initially loads and `dojo.subscribe("partialrefresh-complete", null, function(method, form, refreshId) {...}` will run the code aftedr a partial refresh.

Here's sample code I used for converting a DataView's category column images to Font Awesome icons, so the `Behavior = {...}` bit will need amending.

```
Behavior = {
    // Convert xp:pagers to Bootstrap
    ".catColumn a img": {
        found: function(img_node) {
            var imgSrc = dojo.getNodeProp(img_node, "alt").toLowerCase();
            if (imgSrc.indexOf("collapse") >= 0) {
                dojo.place('<i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i>&nbsp;', img_node, 'replace');
            } else {
                dojo.place('<i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>&nbsp;', img_node, 'replace');
            }
        }
    }
}

dojo.ready(function() {
    dojo.behavior.add(Behavior);
    dojo.behavior.apply();
});

//Make sure that future pagers are also straightened out
dojo.subscribe("partialrefresh-complete", null, function(method, form, refreshId) {
    dojo.behavior.apply();
});
```

Comment: If you want to have total control over the layout, a repeat control may be the best way to go. But it may mean changing existing XPages / applications to get a consistent look and feel